Facing error while adding web maps in Exp Builder Dev 1.15
We have recently installed offline version of ArcGIS Experience Builder 1.15 Dev edition.
Error: "Item does not exist or is inaccessible"
Surely the item exists, what permissions can this be missing? Maps are shared publicly.
We are not able to add any maps into the builder, unsure what is triggering this and if anyone can guide us with the solution/workaround?

